# How to count total spin degeneracies for many spin one half particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, electrons, quantum-spin, hilbert-space

Given the spin operator for particle $j$
\begin{align}
\bar{S}_{j} = \left( \bigotimes_{k=1}^{j-1} I_{k} \right)
\otimes \left(\tfrac{\hbar}{2}\bar{\sigma}\right)_{j} \otimes
\left( \bigotimes_{k=j+1}^{N} I_{k} \right)
\end{align}
how do I count the degeneracies of the total angualr momentum for all electrons together? I assume that the total angular momentum for $N$ electrons is
\begin{align}
J^2
=
\left|
\sum_{i=1}^{N}\bar{S}_{i}
\right|
\end{align}

Qmechanic suggests the solution
$$m_{n,k}~=~ \frac{n!~(n + 1 - 2k)}{k!~ (n + 1 - k)!}. $$
from
[Problem counting spin states](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/66834/problem-counting-spin-states?rq=1).