# How many eigenstates for four (non-identical) spin 1/2 particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, representation-theory

**Question**

Consider a system of four non-identical spin 1/2 particles. Find the possible values for the total spin and state the number of eigenstates for each of these.

**Attempt**

So I coupled S1 and S2 to get S12 and I also coupled S3 and S4 to get S34. I will then couple S12 and S34 to get S1234: (states are in the form (S1, S2, S12, m))

Eigenstates for S12: {(1/2, 1/2, 1, 1),(1/2, 1/2, 1, 0),(1/2, 1/2, 1, -1),(1/2, 1/2, 0, 0)}

Eigenstates for S34: {(1/2, 1/2, 1, 1),(1/2, 1/2, 1, 0),(1/2, 1/2, 1, -1),(1/2, 1/2, 0, 0)}

Eigenstates for S1234: {(1,1,2,2),(1,1,2,1),(1,1,2,0),(1,1,2,-1),(1,1,2,-2),(1,1,1,1),(1,1,1,0),(1,1,1,-1),(1,1,0,0),(1,0,1,1),(1,0,1,0),(1,0,1,-1),(0,1,1,1),(0,1,1,0),(0,1,1,-1),(0,0,0,0)}

That would make 16 different states but i'm not sure about the last 7 states (it disagrees with the answers my friends have). Cheers!

Comment: Your answer is correct: $\frac{1}{2} \otimes \frac{1}{2} \otimes \frac{1}{2} \otimes \frac{1}{2} = \left( 0 \oplus 1 \right) \otimes \left( 0 \oplus 1 \right) = 0^2 \oplus 1^3 \oplus 2$. Two singlets, three triplets, and one quintet giving 16 states in total. Note that these are only eigenstates of non-identical particles because some of these states belong to higher-dimensional representations of the symmetric group; they transform to one another after exchange. This is called parastatistics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem counting spin states](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/66834/problem-counting-spin-states)

Answer (score 2):

As Praan confirmed, you are fine. Your result is the *n*=4 case of the [general expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients#Tensor_product_space) for composing spin 1/2 doublets, (so here denoted by their dimensionality, **2**),
$$
{\mathbf 2}^{\otimes n} = \bigoplus_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}~
\Bigl( {n+1-2k \over n+1}  {n+1 \choose k}\Bigr)~~({\mathbf n}+{\mathbf 1}-{\mathbf 2}{\mathbf k})~,
$$
where  $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$  is the integer floor function--the largest integer smaller than the argument, and the number preceding the
**boldface** irreducible representation dimensionality (2 *j* +1) label (here just **5**, **3** and **1** ) indicates multiplicity of that
representation in the C-G reduction, here 1, 3, and 2, so that 16=5+9+2 states.