# Addition of $N$ spin halves

Tags: angular-momentum, quantum-spin, group-representations, representation-theory

If I have two spin-halves, then
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2} \otimes  \frac{1}{2} = 0 \oplus 1.
\end{align}
If I have three spin-halves, then
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2} \otimes  \frac{1}{2} \otimes \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2} \oplus \frac{1}{2} \oplus \frac{3}{2},
\end{align}
and for four
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2} \otimes\frac{1}{2} \otimes  \frac{1}{2} \otimes \frac{1}{2} = 0 \oplus 0 \oplus 1 \oplus 1 \oplus 1 \oplus 2.
\end{align}

What's the decomposition into irreducible representations for $N$ (say even) spin-1/2s? That is, how many spin-$0$s do I get, how many spin-$1$s, how many spin-$2$s etc... There will be only one spin-$N/2$.

Of course one can solve this by induction, but on the off-chance that someone knows what it is by heart?

Comment: Is [this](https://oeis.org/A008313) the right formula?

Comment: Duplicate of [249635](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/222774/)

Comment: [Catalan's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_triangle) .