# Isospin symmetry as an $SU(2)$ symmetry

Tags: homework-and-exercises, representation-theory, lie-algebra, isospin-symmetry

The generators for the isospin symmetry are given by

$$
T_{+}=\left|\uparrow\rangle\langle\downarrow\right|,
 \qquad
 T_{-}=\left|\downarrow\rangle\langle\uparrow\right|, 
\qquad 
T_{3}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\left|\uparrow\rangle\langle\uparrow\right|-\left|\downarrow\rangle\langle\downarrow\right|\right),$$

where $\left|\uparrow\right\rangle$ and $\left|\downarrow\right\rangle$ form a $2$-dimensional basis of states.

---

In the $2$-dimensional basis of states $\left|\uparrow\right\rangle$ and $\left|\downarrow\right\rangle$, the generators $T_+$, $T_-$ and $T_3$ can be written as

$T_{+}=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1\\
    0 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix},\qquad T_{+}=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0\\
    1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix},\qquad T_{3}=\begin{bmatrix}
    1/2 & 0\\
    0 & -1/2\\
\end{bmatrix}.$

---

1. The generators $T_+$, $T_-$ and $T_3$ obey the $SU(2)$ algebra $[T_{i},T_{j}]=i\epsilon_{ijk}T_{k}$ (with $\epsilon_{+-3}=1$). However, I do not get the correct commutation relations using the matrix representations of the generators.
2. Is it possible to rewrite the generators $T_+$, $T_-$ and $T_3$ in terms of an arbitrary number of states?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [representation matrices of the rotation algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_group_SO(3)#A_note_on_Lie_algebra)?

Comment: Yes, I am! I forgot that $T_+$ and $T_-$ are ladder operators. I need to write them in terms of $T_1$ and $T_2$ and then show that the commutation relations are satisfied.

Comment: Do you have any answer to my second question?

Comment: You Kronecker-multiply your states (add their spins) and Clebsch decompose into a series of arbitrary spins, as your angular momentum text should tell you. You then rotate *those* as per the above link. To add N spin 1/2s, see, e.g. The Catalan ladder in [249635](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/222774/how-many-eigenstates-for-four-non-identical-spin-1-2-particles/249635#249635).