# Lorentz representation of totally symmetric tensors?

Tags: special-relativity, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, group-theory, representation-theory

Pretty much the title. A rank 1 tensor is $(1/2,1/2)$, a symmetric rank 2 tensor is $(0,0)+(1,1)$. I'm curious how this generalizes to rank $n$ totally symmetric tensors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A symmetric traceless tensor of rank $\ell$ is $(\ell/2,\ell/2)$. If you want the reducible representation corresponding to a symmetric tensor, you have to add back the traces, which are lower rank tensors. So the representation is
$$
\bigoplus_{k \equiv \,\ell \;\mathrm{mod}\;2}^\ell\, (k/2,k/2)\,.
$$
Every trace reduces the rank by two, so the starting point of the sum is $0$ (1) if $\ell$ is even (odd).

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: There is already a correct answer by MannyC. The totally symmetric rank-$n$ tensor product of a 4-vector representation decomposes as
$$\begin{align}\begin{pmatrix}{\bf  n+3} \cr{\bf  3}\end{pmatrix} ~=~&{\bf 4}^{\odot n}~=~(\underbrace{{\bf 2}_L}_{j_L=1/2}\otimes \underbrace{{\bf 2}_R}_{j_R=1/2})^{\odot n}\cr
~=~&\bigoplus_{k=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}  \underbrace{({\bf n+1-2k})_L}_{j_L=n/2-k} \otimes \underbrace{({\bf n+1-2k})_R}_{j_R=n/2-k},\end{align}\tag{1}$$
cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149455/2451) & [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66834/2451) Phys.SE posts.

Longer explanation:

1. Let $$V_L~\cong~\mathbb{C}^2\qquad\text{and}\qquad V_R~\cong~\mathbb{C}^2\tag{2}$$ denote the left and right Weyl spinor representations, respectively, of the double cover $G=SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ of the [restricted Lorentz group $SO^+(1,3;\mathbb{R})$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group). Let $(e_{\alpha})_{\alpha=1,2}$ and $(e_{\dot{\alpha}})_{\dot{\alpha}=\dot{1},\dot{2}}$ denote bases for the vector spaces (2), respectively. The vector spaces (2) are endowed with antisymmetric forms, i.e. the Levi-Civita symbols $\epsilon_{\alpha\beta}$ and $\epsilon_{\dot{\alpha}\dot{\beta}}$, respectively.
2. The tensor product
   $$V=V_L\otimes_{\mathbb{C}} V_R~\cong~\mathbb{C}^{4} \tag{3}$$
   is isometric to the complexified Minkowski$^1$ space, with metric $$\eta_{\mu\nu}~\sim~ \eta_{\alpha\dot{\alpha},\beta\dot{\beta}} ~=~\epsilon_{\alpha\beta}\epsilon_{\dot{\alpha}\dot{\beta}}.\tag{4}$$
   The vector space $V$ has a basis $$(e_{\alpha}\otimes e_{\dot{\alpha}})_{\alpha=1,2;\dot{\alpha}=\dot{1},\dot{2}}.\tag{5}$$
3. The $(j_L,j_R)$ [irreducible representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_representation) of $G$ is
   $$ 
   V_L^{\odot 2j_L}\otimes_{\mathbb{C}}V_R^{\odot 2j_R}, \qquad
   j_L, j_R~\in~ \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{N}_0, \tag{6} $$
   with basis
   $$ \left(e_1^{\odot m_L}\odot e_2^{\odot (2j_L- m_L)}\otimes e_{\dot{1}}^{\odot m_R}\odot e_{\dot{2}}^{\odot (2j_R- m_R)}\right)_{0\leq m_L\leq 2j_L;0\leq m_R\leq 2j_R}, \tag{7} $$
   and dimension $(2j_L+1)(2j_R+1)$, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/149455/2451) Phys.SE post.
4. The symmetric tensor product $$V^{\odot n}, \qquad n~\in~ \mathbb{N}_0,\tag{8}$$
   has dimension $ \binom{n+3}{3}, $
   and corresponds to a symmetric tensor field $S^{\mu_1 \ldots\mu_{n}}.$
5. Similarly, a $n$th symmetric tensor field
   $$\eta_{\mu_1\mu_2}\ldots\eta_{\mu_{2k-1}\mu_{2k}} S^{\mu_1 \ldots\mu_{n}}\tag{9}$$
   with $k\in \mathbb{N}_0$ traces corresponds to $V^{\odot (n-2k)}$ with dimension $ \binom{n-2k+3}{3}. $
6. We can split
   $$\begin{align} V^{\odot n}~\cong~&\underbrace{V^{\odot (n-2)}}_{\text{single-trace}}+\underbrace{ V_L^{\odot n}\otimes V_R^{\odot n}}_{\text{traceless}}, \cr
    \binom{n+3}{3}~=~&\binom{n+1}{3}+(n+1)^2
   .\end{align}\tag{10} $$
   Intuitively, eq. (10) can be understood as follows: The left/undotted and right/dotted bases commute in the irrep $V_L^{\odot n}\otimes V_R^{\odot n}$ but not in $V^{\odot n}$. The non-commutativity in $V^{\odot 2}$ is associated with pairs of non-zero trace.
7. Repeated applications of eq. (10) lead to the sought-for result (1)
   $$ V^{\odot n}~\cong~\bigoplus_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor} \underbrace{V_L^{\odot (n-2k)}}_{j_L=n/2-k}\otimes \underbrace{V_R^{\odot (n-2k)}}_{j_R=n/2-k}, \tag{11}$$
   cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/545943/2451) related Phys.SE post.

--

$^1$ The word 'Minkowski' is here only a semantic label since the Minkowski signature is irrelevant in the complexification $\mathbb{C}^4$.

Comment: Notes for later: As representations of the subgroup $H=SU(2)\subseteq G$ the left and right Weyl representations are isomorphic, so that the tensor representation (6) decomposes as a direct sum of $H$-irreps via Clebsch-Gordon.