# Why does general irreducible representation $(A, A)$ of a quantum field correspond to traceless symmetric tensor of rank $2A$?

Tags: angular-momentum, field-theory, quantum-spin, group-theory, representation-theory

I understand that under rotation, we will have components that transform like integer spin $(2A, 2A-1, ...... 0)$ from decomposition of $(A, A)$ representation. The scalar is the trace, therefore other components are traceless. And, I can see why $2A$ component will be traceless symmetric tensor, but I don't understand why Weinberg says on p. 231 below eq. (5.6.18) in section 5.6 of Volume I that

> "$(A, A)$ field contain terms with only integer spins $(2A, 2A-1, ...... 0)$ and corresponds to a traceless symmetric tensor of rank $2A$."

I think he means that the whole field representation corresponds to a traceless symmetric tensor of rank $2A$.

Comment: The answer to the last sentence (v5) is Yes. Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/545943/2451

Comment: Thank you for the link, but seems like the link doesn't seem to answer my question, I was asking *why* is (A, A) representation symmetric traceless tensor. I think it is because as Weinberg says all terms are integer spins, which have symmetric traceless tensor representations. For example, for spin-2, we can use symmetric traceless tensor in 3-d which has 5 independent components as expected.

Comment: The _why_ is essentially the content of eq. (10) in my answer.