Why order matters when combining angular momentum
This seems like the answer should be trivial but when decomposing the direct product of 4 spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ states into a direct sum, one gets two singlets, namely
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(\mid{\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow}\rangle \pm \mid{\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow}\rangle\right).\tag{1}$$
This is assuming one follows the normal textbook procedure using the Clebsch Gordan coefficients to combine the spins one at a time. However, if one hastily combines the spins into pairs of singlets, i.e. $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( \mid\uparrow\downarrow\rangle - \mid\downarrow\uparrow\rangle\right) \otimes \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( \mid\uparrow\downarrow\rangle - \mid\downarrow\uparrow\rangle\right) \tag{2}$$
then one obtains a state that superficially is annihilated by $\vec{S}_1 + \vec{S}_2$ and $\vec{S}_3 + \vec{S}_4$ and so one expects it to be annihilated by $\vec{S}_1 + \vec{S}_2 + \vec{S}_3 + \vec{S}_4$.
Yet this state is clearly not part of the above representations.
My suspicion is that while the singlets are invariant under global $SU(2)$ rotations that is not the case for local ones, and that the quick and dirty method ends up in a different choice of basis.
So my question is why does combining spins iteratively produce a more symmetric state than combining them as pairs, and where does that break down?

The tensor product $\otimes$ is associative. Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/222774/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66834/2451 and links therein.

Suggestion to the post (v5): Consider to check & correct eq. (1).

@Qmechanic, Looking at the output of my code with fresh eyes suggests you are correct. Also https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.0882 seems to confirm. Do I delete the question?
